# Memory Over Flow if I Use a lot of session

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it Possible for Server Memory to Overflow if I use too many Sessions in Asp.net Core?

For example, what happens if I have an e-commerce web application and I Use session for store user shopping cart information and a large number of user create a shopping cart in one time .

Comment: [Is session stored in client side or server side](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6665619/327083)

Comment: Otherwise, if you have experienced a real exception please include the full exception details and the code which produces it.

Comment: server-side session vars do take up resources.  You might consider using a database to store cart items.  You can persist the items for longer and you won't need any session vars.  You can check for updates to those items when the user visits their cart or logs in again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it Possible for Server Memory to Overflow if I use too many Sessions in Asp.net Core?

In my opinion, if you store all the things into the memory, you may not face this error, but you will face the application slow response issue. If you have many user to access your web site, your application's memory usage may reach thee 100%. This will make all the application failed in the server.

If you still want to store the data into the session, the right solution is set the session provider to use redis, this could avoid the high memory issue. More details about how to use it, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-6.0#session-state).

Comment: thank you it was so helpful ...